# Obj C to Swift conversion

Tags: objective-c, swift, for-loop

Objective C:

```
- (void)stickerViewDidTapDeleteControl:(StickerView *)stickerView {
    NSLog(@"Tap[%zd] DeleteControl", stickerView.tag);
    for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[StickerView class]])
        {
            [(StickerView *)subView performTapOperation];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this line in objective C, Its working fine, but when I converting this to Swift 4. it's not working.

Below is my swift code converted from Objective c.

```
 func stickerViewDidTapDeleteControl(_ stickerView: StickerView?) {
    if let aTag = stickerView?.tag {
        print("Tap[\(aTag)] DeleteControl")
    }

    for subView: UIView? in self.view.subviews
    {
        if (subView is StickerView)
        {

            let subViewNew: StickerView? = subView as? StickerView

            subViewNew?.performTapOperation()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Crash? Compile error? Unexpected result? You need to explain what is happening.

Comment: While you're right, I assume he means that the `performTapOperation` method isn't called.

Comment: if (subView is StickerView)
     My problem is this condition is not called.

Comment: But, I don't even know if your Objective C code does what you expect because the `stickerView` argument is used only to print a tag (and then you iterate on subviews and you're looking for a StickerView instance (if there are multiple StickerView then why not, but if there is only one, then you have your `stickerView` in your argument))

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can write the Swift version in one line

```
self.view.subviews.compactMap{$0 as? StickerView}.forEach{ $0.performTapOperation() }
```

`compactMap` filters the `StickerView` items and `forEach` calls the method on each item.

To consider the `break` statement – call the method only once – use

```
self.view.subviews.compactMap{$0 as? StickerView}.first?.performTapOperation()
```

Due to optional chaining if `subviews` doesn't contain any `StickerView` items the line does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (more 'swifty'):

```
let stickerViews = self.view.subviews.filter{$0 is StickerView}
stickerViews.forEach { $0.performTapOperation() }
```

(Typed in browser, not tested)

Comment: technically, you directly `compactMap { $0 as? StickerView }` to directly get `[StickerView]`.

Comment: Yes, that's also possible.

Answer (score -1):

By not working, I assume you meant that the `performTapOperation` method wasn't called.

First, in your for loop, it's not necessary to cast because the `subviews` array is already an array of `UIView`.

Then, you can simply use **optional binding** (and your original code containing a `break` suggests that there is only one `StickerView` in your subviews).

```
func stickerViewDidTapDeleteControl(_ stickerView: StickerView?) {
    if let aTag = stickerView?.tag {
        print("Tap[\(aTag)] DeleteControl")
    }

    for subView in self.view.subviews
    {
        if let subViewNew = subView as? StickerView {
            subViewNew.performTapOperation()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, Thanks. can you explain?

Comment: Well, it's basic Swift :) With the `if let` statement (called an **Optional Binding**) you make sure that the subview is a `StickerView` and you get a non-optional object, meaning you can safely call the `performTapOperation` method.

Comment: @Koen's approach is good too but he assumes that you may have multiple stickerViews and call the `performTapOperation` method on each one, whereas you did put a `break` in your original code.

Comment: Ah, thanks - I missed that `break`.